# How much land does a land card represent?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, game-lore

Thematically, how much land is a single land card supposed to represent?  (It's for a story where the Magic: The Gathering card game is going to become kind of-sort of real through ignorance and stupid amounts of raw, untapped magical talent. ...yes, it is Harry Potter.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is somewhere between "it depends" and "it's more of an abstract concept", but either way it's unlikely that the question is answerable within the scope of the site.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'll go think something up, then.  Much appreciated.

Comment: This might be more at home on [scifi.se]'s [magic the gathering tag](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering), because it's a lore question, and we don't often deal with that topic, while fictional universe lore is their bread & butter.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I may just do that.  I honestly had no idea where to start, but prefer to use already existing lore for stories when I'm using their universe for a playground, rather than make things up willy-nilly.

Comment: I think this question works fine here.

Comment: It seems obvious to me that an Island represents one entire island, a Mountain represents one entire mountain, a Forest represents one entire forest, etc. The art may depict more or less, but that doesn't change what it represents in my opinion.

Comment: Lore is as much a part of games as rules and mechanics. I don't see the scope of this site as limited to what's printed in rulebooks.

Comment: @Jefromi Lore is in scope, but primarily-opinion-based questions are not. It's one thing when there's good source for the lore, but on this question no one's found any - the accepted answer is just a very rough guess based on the pictures.

Comment: @BenjaminCosman The validity of the question doesn't hinge on what an eager new user OP chooses to accept. And while that answer could be more detailed and thorough, basing things on art is not inherently opinion-based: Wizards gives explicit instructions for artists so that the art conveys what they wish.

Comment: @Jefromi Does WotC share those instructions with the rest of the community? If so, then that seems like a great answer to this question.

Comment: @Rainbolt Not for all cards, but they do sometimes quote them in articles, and sometimes artists post about their art (process, high-res images, etc) and include them. There are also creative team members who answer questions on social media. And... they publish [art books](https://www.amazon.com/Art-Magic-Gathering-Zendikar/dp/142158249X) that have a lot of extra information, not just the art. Anyways, I agree that stuff like that would make a great answer, but haven't gone and researched - I really just wanted to make the point that this is not just an opinion-based question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the more special lands depict a city, or only a single structure. For example [Seat of the Synod](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSeat%20of%20the%20Synod%5d), or [Strip mine](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStrip%20mine%5d). Others show a very specific patch of nature, that's probably a bit larger than city-size.

Perhaps you could assume, based on this, that the other more common lands are about county-sized?

Comment: That is an excellent suggestion and makes a great deal of sense, thank you.

Comment: Again, thank you.  I think I'm just a guest, as it wouldn't let me click the up arrow, but I'm not really on forums and such all that much, so I suppose it's fine.  Have a nice day!

Comment: I don't really get how you go from city-sized to country-sized "just because". Also, are we talking about a Canada-sized country, or the Netherlands?

Comment: @Matt Not country, but county without the R. Municipality if you will. An area akin a baronie or duchy perhaps.

Comment: @user17839 just a side note, stack exchange isn't a forums. Just saying :)

Answer (score 7):

Thematically a land card (or permanent) doesn't represent any physical land, but rather represents the planeswalker's bond with the lands that they visit as they move across the multiverse, they then draw mana through that bond in order to cast spells (although most of the modern Magic stories ignore this).

Every type of land in the multiverse has a specific kind of mana tied to it, and as such forming a bond with that land will yield that specific type of mana when you tap into it (hence the term tapping a land).

Source: the [Learn to Play Magic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GadqHggATe8) videos.

Comment: is it not the case that the mana comes from leylines within that land? such that each "land" is specifically sufficient land to contain a leyline, and that leyline generates mana based on it's surroundings? I could be conflating things here though

Comment: This sounds like correct lore, but does it address the question at all?

Comment: @Patters I'd have to go find some sources, but from memory it seemed more like the as the ley-lines flow accross particular types of land the mana in them gets 'flavoured' with the type that is associated with that land.

Comment: @BenjaminCosman Answer adjusted to more directly address the question,